# How wouldn't Zuko (& Azula?) know they're descended from Roku when in the comics Ursa was sought out precisely for this?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In ATLA s3, it's a huge surprise for the viewers that wow Roku was Zuko's mom's grandfather. But then in the comics iirc Ursa was sought out specifically because of Roku. Seems quite nonsensical to hide this from Zuko & Azula. It'd probably be a well-known fact not just in the fire nation but even outside.

Come on. It's totally a retcon right?